# Is my SSD towards the end of the line of its life?

Tags: linux, ssd, smart

**Edit**
Corrected units - question stil stands

I've got a [Samsung SSD 840 EVO 1TB](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/840-evo-sata-iii), operational since 2014.
I had another, same model, operational since 2013 and it failed ~3 days go.
My fear is that the one from 2014 is also towards the end of the line for its life and currently I have the total LBAs written of:

```
8835594656
```

Which ends up being `~4.523 TB`. I believe the total *warranty-ed* max writes on this model is `~1000 TB`, hence it seems to be well within its supported life.
Unfortunately I can't find any official documentation about this: I'm not sure if I should replace it before it dies or not.

What would you recommend?

`smarctl -x` output is:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 EVO 1TB
Serial Number:    ****************
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 8a0793dd4
Firmware Version: EXT0CB6Q
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Sep  1 14:23:19 2019 BST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Unexpected SCT status 0x0001 (action_code=4, function_code=2)
Wt Cache Reorder: Unknown (SCT Feature Control command failed)

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (15000) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 250) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   098   098   000    -    6186
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   096   096   000    -    3671
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--C-   099   099   000    -    4
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--C-   100   100   010    -    0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       PO--C-   100   100   010    -    0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O--CK   070   042   000    -    30
195 ECC_Error_Rate          -O-RC-   200   200   000    -    0
199 CRC_Error_Count         -OSRCK   100   100   000    -    0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      -O--C-   099   099   000    -    163
241 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--CK   099   099   000    -    8835594656
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      1  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      1  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xce       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xde           SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       1 (0x0001)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    30 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:      ?/ ? Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:      ?/ ? Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/43154

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         10 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        10 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      ?/ ? Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            ?/ ? Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (0)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
   1    2019-08-31 17:10     ?  -
 ...    ..(126 skipped).    ..  -
   0    2019-09-01 14:20     ?  -

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2            2  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0010  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x0013  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC
```

Comment: Are your unit conversations correct? Because off hand back then SSD  drives NOT designed for write heave IO were usually rated for a write capacity of +- 10% of the drive capacity *per day* over a period of 1-3 years and 4.5 TB of cumulative writes for a 1 TB drive is in that regard peanuts and not indicative of imminent failure (On mobile now and can’t really read the other stats you posted)

Comment: You're probably right, looks like if life is 1000 TB, not GB, then I should be fine for a while longer...

Comment: Corrected units, my question stands though... Don't seem to be able to find max writes for this SSD...

Comment: Although Samsung didn't publish any warranty TBW for the 840 EVO, they published the ones for the 500GB 840 Pro (73TBW) and the 1TB 850 EVO (150TBW). Between these may give you a rough idea of the maximum warranty they'd consider covering. Testing and calculations done by [AnandTech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7173/samsung-ssd-840-evo-review-120gb-250gb-500gb-750gb-1tb-models-tested/3) does indicate that it can go a lot lot farther then the warranty suggests though.

Comment: Thanks very much - this is what I'm after. Want to post as answer?